# Function inside a public function?

Tags: php, class, function

```
class ea_framework {

    public function outer() {

        function inner() {

        }

    }

}
```

This doesn't seem to be possible?

I'm really new to PHP Classes any advice would be appreciated!

Here's my test case:

```
# Site Class
class ea_framework {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init() {
        $this->header();            
    }

    public function header() {

        function head_start() {

            # Doctype
            echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
            # Begin HTML
            echo "<html class='".agent()."'>\n";
            # Begin HEAD
            echo "<head>\n";

        }

        $this->head_start();

    }

}

$bro = new ea_framework();
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ea_framework::head_start() in /home/tfbox/domains/ibrogram.com/public_html/i/construction/core/run.php on line 31
```

Comment: Why do you say that it "doesn't seem to be possible"? What happens in your testcase when you try it? What _is_ your testcase?

Comment: What's the goal with this anyway?

Comment: @deceze Learning curve. Introducing myself to Classes, not going down that great so far lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [works for me in PHP 5.2.5](http://codepad.org/ldf5S42n) [and in PHP 5.2.11](http://www.ideone.com/vtNUC).

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) doesn't state any notable version requirements, so I'd expect this to work in any PHP5 version — and perhaps late PHP4, too.

---

**Update**

Your testcase is slightly broken, in that your inner function is *not* a member of your class, yet you are trying to call it as such.

The inner function actually becomes a *global* function (and you will get a redefinition error if you call the outer function more than once!).

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

So, I'd recommend not doing this.

If you still really want this, call `$head_start()`, not `$this->head_start()`.

Comment: How do I make it a member of my class?

Comment: @Brogrammer: Make it a normal member function. In PHP 5.3+ you _can_ assign a lambda to a class member variable (`$this->someMember = function() { ... }`), but ... why!? This is a bit yucky and usually not desired unless you really need the closure.

Comment: So is this not a good way to go? What would you do, considering the Class as it stands.

Comment: @Brogrammer: I have no idea why you went for an inner function, or what your goal with it is. So I cannot suggest anything.

Comment: Alright, I'll drop the inner function and just make better use of the functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP 5.3 or higher, you can try

```
$inner = function() { ... }
...
$inner();
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, but isn't very useful.

PHP will execute `outer()` the first time it's called. Inside, it will find a function declaration for the function `inner()`, which it will parse. Now you have the *global* function `inner` available for use. Note, the function is not part of the class, it's just a regular global function. If `outer()` is ever called again though, PHP will again encounter the function declaration for a function called `inner` and will stop execution, complaining that you `can't redeclare function inner on line ...`.

Therefore, while it works (depending on what you want to achieve), it's not a very useful pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes sense. What would you suggest I do instead?

Comment: Just make it a regular class method, like `init` and `header`. Make that function `private` if you don't want external code to call it. Or just put the code in `header`, I don't know why you'd need to wrap it in a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use this arrow function inside the public function of PHP OOPS

$fn1 = fn($x) => $x + $y;

For More:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35007596)